# Change Date Format in PHP HTML form results

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I'm just starting to learn php and I've tried to research an answer to this but I can't find an answer that fits my situation.  Remember, I'm a noob so please explain in detail.

Webpage where results are shown: https://fireytech.com/FireytechDatabase/hello.php

I have a php select query that pulls a field from my mysql database where a date / timestamp is saved.  When I get the echo results of the query in my html form, it displays this date field in this format: 2022-01-31 00:00:00.  I would like it to show as: 01/31/2022 (no time).  Below is my form's code.  How would I change date format for my "DateReceived" and "DateLastEdited" fields?

```
<?php

require '../../db_php/dbconnection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM
            Tickets 
        Left JOIN
            Clients
        ON Tickets.CustomerNumber=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Contacts
        ON Contacts.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Equipment
        ON Equipment.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        
        WHERE Equipment.PRINT = '-1' AND Contacts.DispatchContact = '-1' AND TicketStatus = 'Active' AND NOT TicketSubStatus = 'CUSTOMER PICKUP' AND NOT TaskSubType = 'ON-SITE'
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo"<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Ticket Type</td><td>Ticket Number</td><td>Date Received</td><td>Last Edited</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Followup By</td><td>Sub Status</td><td>Repair Type</td><tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['TaskSubType']}</td><td>{$row['TicketNumber']}</td><td>{$row['DateReceived']}</td><td>{$row['DateLastEdited']}</td><td>{$row['ContactLast']}</td><td>{$row['FollowupBy']}</td><td>{$row['TicketSubStatus']}</td><td>{$row['ItemType']}</td></tr>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 records";
}

echo"</table>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform the dates to the format you want, simply put

```
$dr= date("Y/d/m", strtotime($row['DateReceived']));
$dl= date("Y/d/m", strtotime($row['DateLastEdited']));
echo "<tr><td>{$row['TaskSubType']}</td><td>{$row['TicketNumber']}</td><td>{$dr}</td><td>{$dl}</td><td>{$row['ContactLast']}</td><td>{$row['FollowupBy']}</td><td>{$row['TicketSubStatus']}</td><td>{$row['ItemType']}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: That makes total sense to me; process the date format ahead of the echo string and include it in the string.  It worked so well I was literally able to copy and paste it!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `date_format(DateReceived,'%m/%d/%Y')` in sql, if you want to change date format in php use function `date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['DateLastEdited' ]))`

Example in sql

```
$sql = "SELECT date_format(DateReceived,'%m/%d/%Y') as DateReceived   FROM
            Tickets 
        Left JOIN
            Clients
        ON Tickets.CustomerNumber=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Contacts
        ON Contacts.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Equipment
        ON Equipment.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        
        WHERE Equipment.PRINT = '-1' AND Contacts.DispatchContact = '-1' AND TicketStatus = 'Active' AND NOT TicketSubStatus = 'CUSTOMER PICKUP' AND NOT TaskSubType = 'ON-SITE'
";
```

Example in php

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['TaskSubType']}</td><td>{$row['TicketNumber']}</td><td>{date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row['DateReceived']))}</td><td>{date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['DateLastEdited']))}</td><td>{$row['ContactLast']}</td><td>{$row['FollowupBy']}</td><td>{$row['TicketSubStatus']}</td><td>{$row['ItemType']}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  For some reason that didn't work but the other answer did so I'm good to go on that issue.

Comment: When using the asterisk to fetch all fields, you'd get a duplicate field `DateReceived`. That's why this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date_format(date_create($date),"Y-m-d");
```